# SVG and PNG resizing in SCSS background property

Tags: html, css, svg, png, scale

When I'm trying resize icon I have quire weird issue. Seems like only picture borders change, not picture itself. Icon image stay the same size. Probably I do it wrong. I've fought this is PNG issue but with SVG the same story. I've checked in Chrome and Firefox both show the same.

```
  .icon {
     display: inline-block;
     height: 24px;
     width: 24px;
     margin-right: 1px;
     image-rendering: crisp-edges;
     background-size: contain;
     &.login{  background: url(../img/ico-login.svg) no-repeat center   center;  }
     &.logout{  background: url(../img/ico-logout.svg) no-repeat center center;  }
  }
```

I've trying change height and width parameters as font-size as well. And have the same result. Probably background property just can't be apply scaling thing.

Comment: Could you provide a **JSFiddle** or **CodePen** with the concrete example to help you?

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible: http://codepen.io/ThiRaBrTNK/pen/PqxRQK Try removing `width` and `height` attributes from svg, if they are there.